# Как спарсить строку после определенного символа

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте, есть ли такая функция PHP или выражение которое парсило бы сроку в переменной  после знака =(строковая переменная и если в ней есть = то происходил парсинг, но другая часть до = не парсилась, спасибо большое) мучаюсь уже как 2 дня не могу найти ответа в Интернете.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дана строка, так и работаем со строкой:

```
$str = 'str=1';
$result = substr(strstr($str, '='), 1, strlen($str));
echo $result; # Выведет: 1
```

Или так:

```
$str = 'str=1';
$result = substr($str, strpos($str, '=') + 1, strlen($str));
echo $result; # Выведет: 1
```

Comment: Ну да, так красивее

Comment: Во втором случае echo $result лишнее

Comment: @MDJHD, спасибо, поправил

Answer (score 8):

Попробуйте (упрощенно без проверок):

```
$string_array = explode("=", $string);
echo $string_array[1]; // строка после равно
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $str = "=1=2=3=4";

    preg_match_all('|=(.+?)|is', $str, $match);

    var_dump($match[1]);

 array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "2"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "4"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В версии PHP 7.4 лучше (быстрее) так:

```
$str = 'str=1';
$result = substr($str, strpos($str, '=') + 1);
```

Нет необходимости вычислять длину строки. Опуская последний аргумент мы получим строку до ее конца.
Осторожно! Будет вырезана подстрока **после первого** вхождения сиимвола "=".